# MongoDB C# driver timeout

Tags: c#, mongodb, connection-string

I am trying to post some data into my remote mongodb instance which is a replica set, however I am getting a timeout exception saying that the host is not found?  I have also read around and added `?connect=replicaSet` at the end of the connection string but this did not help.

Here is my connection string

```
private MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.250.8.1:27017,10.250.8.2:27017,10.250.8.3:27017?connect=replicaSet");
```

and here is the exception that has been thrown:

```
{"A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", ConnectionMode : \"ReplicaSet\", Type : \"ReplicaSet\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/wsmongodb001:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/wsmongodb001:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<CreateStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.<HeartbeatAsync>d__42.MoveNext()\" }, { ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/wsmongodb002:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/wsmongodb002:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<CreateStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.<HeartbeatAsync>d__42.MoveNext()\" }, { ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/wsmongodb003:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/wsmongodb003:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<ConnectAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.<CreateStreamAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.<HeartbeatAsync>d__42.MoveNext()\" }] }."}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the most important part of your error message:

```json
Client view of cluster state is
{  
   ClusterId: "1",
   ConnectionMode: "ReplicaSet",
   Type: "ReplicaSet",
   State: "Disconnected",
   Servers: [{  
      ServerId: {
         ClusterId: 1,
         EndPoint: "Unspecified/wsmongodb001:27017"
      },
      EndPoint: "Unspecified/wsmongodb001:27017",
      State: "Disconnected",
      Type: "Unknown",
      HeartbeatException: "[...] System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known [...]"
   }]
}
```

Note the *"No such host is known"* part of the field `HeartbeatException`.

Your replica set is configured with host names instead of IP addresses. Apparently, your client application cannot resolve `wsmongodb001` to an IP address.

You will need to:

1. Make sure that your replica set is up and running. Manually connect to one of the servers from the `mongo` shell, run `rs.status()` and check that there is a primary and there are no errors.
2. Make sure that **all** domain names that are configured in your replica set via `rs.conf()` are accessible to your client app. If you are unsure if they are, just open a command prompt on the machine that runs the app and `ping` every domain name.

Comment: I have the same problem connecting with IPs. I am connected with MongoDB compass with the same ConnectionString. I checked with telnet and ping but still the same error shows:  new MongoClient (mongoConnectionString ='mongodb://myuser:mypass@10.201.136.333:27017,10.201.136.334:27017,10.201.136.335:27017/publicadorDB');