# Mongo cluster connection from .Net 4.8 application timing out with No such host is known error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a .Net 4.8 application using the mongo libraries at version 2.2.4.  I know the mongo library is outdated but these are the libraries current production uses and I'm trying to set this up in a new test environment.  There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199471/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-timeout) but, unless I'm missing something, I've confirmed that the destination host:port is accessible from the source.

The connection string in Web.config looks like this:

`<add key="mongoDB-connectionString" value="mongodb://portfolio_dev:redacted@hei03lt.redacted:27017,hei04lt.redacted:27017,hei05lt.redacted:27017/portfolio_dev" />`

When I try to access a page that uses mongo, I get this error:

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector { 
   Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector { 
      AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 
   } 
}. 
Client view of cluster state is { 
   ClusterId : "1", 
   ConnectionMode : "Automatic", 
   Type : "ReplicaSet", 
   State : "Connected", 
   Servers : [
      { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "matchestnc.79:27017" }", EndPoint: "matchestnc.79:27017", State: "Connected", Type: "ReplicaSetOther", WireVersionRange: "[0, 2]" }, 
      { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/hei04lt:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/hei04lt:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
```

From the test server, I have used `Test-NetConnection` to confirm that the port is available:

[image]

This is a very similar (or exact) error to the question I linked above. One suggestion there was to connect and run `rs.status()`. Connecting to all 3 hosts and running `rs.status()` results in the same error message:

```
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
```

I'm not sure what steps I need to take next in order to figure out what the problem here is.